# How can to locate descendant elements with selenium web driver API using JavaScript?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm new in Selenium web driver and I facing some problems trying to locate DOM elements.

Let's say I have a bunch of `<div class="column">...</div>`, and inside them, I have a bunch of `<div class="text">...</div>`.

My question is: **What is the better way to get a specific descendant and click it**?

**Below my code**

```
var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
  .forBrowser('chrome')
  .build();


driver.get('http://www.localhost:4000/');

var columns = [];

driver.findElements(By.css('.column')).then(function(list) {
  columns = list.slice();

  columns[1].findElements(By.css('.text')).then(function(textList) {
    textList[0].click();
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine the selectors and do:

```
driver.findElements(By.css('.column .text'))
```

which would locate all the elements with class `text` inside elements with class `.column`.

And, you could use the [`nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child), [`nth-of-type()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) or other pseudo classes to get to the elements by index inside the selectors, for instance:

```
driver.findElements(By.css('.column:nth-of-type(1) .text:nth-of-type(2)'))
```